# Boolean fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

In my Rails app, I need to store boolean fields in a model. Now, this causes a problem since Sqlite3 (which I use for development) uses the character constants `'t'` and `'f'` for truth values. MySQL however, to which my app will be deployed, uses the literals `true` and `false` (corresponding to tinyints 1 and 0 respectively). This makes the use of SQL conditions problematic, since an expression of the type

```
select * from articles where published = true
```

expressed in Rails as

```
Article.where 'published = true'
```

will fail in Sqlite3 with the message `no such column: true`.

What is the preferred way to handle booleans adapter-portably in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using active record, you would do

```
Article.where(:published => true)
```

You would probably want to take this a step further, and make this a scope

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, where(:published => true)
end
```

So that in your controller you can just go

```
@published_articles = Article.published
```

More information on active_record's query interface here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

You are also using an assignment operation `=` instead of equality comparison `==`

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the scope facility.
Re assignment: That piece of code is not Ruby but SQL, which uses = for equality tests.